# How can I view the wear logs and mobile logs simultaneously for Android?

Tags: wear-os, android-logcat

Android Studio only allows me to view one or the other currently, but I want to see them at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Android Studio (and if you're not by now, you really should be ;^)...

You just need to open two AS windows, and you can point their Android Monitors to different devices. However, the only way I've found to open a second AS window is to open a second project, so if you only have one project currently, you may need to create a new, empty one just for this purpose.